# How do I perform the CallTarget task in a “loop” with MSBuild ItemGroups?

Tags: msbuild

How do I perform the CallTarget task in a "loop" with MSBuild ItemGroups?

I have a property with semicolon separated values, and I want to call target once for each of the values.

For now I have checked and msbuild is autosplitting to multiple Items in Itemgroup:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Version Include="$(Versions)" />
</ItemGroup>
```

What I want to achieve is to have other target called as many times, as there are values in this ItemGroup. 
I know I should use

```
%Version.Identity
```

however I don't see any attribute on CallTarget Task on which it would be possible.

Unfortunately I cannot migrate the target I want to run, to C# or powershell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A target in msbuild is only executed once per invocation. If a target was already run, additional  `<CallTarget>` tasks don't do anything - same as when multiple targets depend on a shared target.

While it is possible to use [target batching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/item-metadata-in-target-batching) by defining metadata-specific `Inputs` or `Outputs`, this doesn't really work with items that don't represent items on disk.

The way to perform the same logic with different inputs would be to use the `<MSBuild>` task to perform an "inner" build which performs multiple builds of the same target with different parameters:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Version Include="1;2;3" />
</ItemGroup>
<MSBuild Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFile)" Targets="DoSthWithVersion" Properties="Version=%(Version.Identity)" />
…

<Target Name="DoSthWithVersion">
  <Message Importance="high" Text="Version is: $(Version)" />
</Target>
```

Note that you will also need to pass any other property that has been generated/changed during the build and is not part of the project file's static property definitions (i.e. only set inside a target).